# How to Give full width and height to a input field

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a HTML table inside which some of my `cells` are of type `input field`, so my issue is that input field is not taking full width and height of cell which is causing problem for me as my table has many rows and i have to show maximum data on a single page.

Here because of input field is not adjusting fully inside the table cell `td` i have to give some height from my side to increase the size of input field which i  don't want

**Code**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate !important;
}

td input {
  width: 100%;
}

table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}


/* background-color: #00998C */

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>AGE</th>
          <th>Occupation</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>govt. employ</td>
          <td><input type="text"></td>



        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

So how can i fully adjust input field inside the table cell with full width and height as table cell `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set td padding to 0,

```
table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
    border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8pt;
    background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set padding to 0

```
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
please replace container class to container-fluid
```

Comment: by that the table will get full width , i want to give full width and height to my input fields inside the `td`